# selectedindexchanged event in radcombobox

Tags: combobox, selectedindex, rad-controls, radcombobox

I have a radcombobox as:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="SelectInitiative" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlInitiative" DataTextField="Initiative_Name" 
                    DataValueField="ID"  EmptyMessage="Select Initiative" Height="200px" 
                      OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectInitiative_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="300px">
                </telerik:RadComboBox></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

            </td>`


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlInitiative" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectPlanningConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Initiative]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And the code for the event is as:

```
 protected void SelectInitiative_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectInitiative.SelectedValue.ToString() != "")
        {
            Session["InitiativeID"] = SelectInitiative.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }
        Label1.Text = "You selected " + e.Value + " item";

    }
```

The problem is that it is neither picking up the value of " selectedvalue" or "e.Value" ,both values are coming out to be empty....... Please help ..........

Comment: Are you sure your datasource correctly completed your "RadCombobox"? Have you debugged to check its contents?

Comment: yes,datasource is fine.radcombobox is showing me all the values

Answer (score 0):

Do you can try this ?

```
protected void SelectInitiative_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (SelectInitiative.SelectedValue.ToString() != "")
        {
            Session["InitiativeID"] = SelectInitiative.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }
        //Or change this line 
        //Label1.Text = "You selected " + e.Value + " item";
        //To this sample
        Label1.Text = "You selected " + SelectInitiative.SelectedValue + " item";

    }

}
```

Or look/check the content of this variable from  RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs properties:

-Text     : is the text of the item that was just selected.

-Value    : is the value of the item that was just selected.

-OldText  : is the text of the item that was previously selected

-OldValue : is the value of the item that was previously selected

Or try this:

```
Label1.Text = "You selected " + SelectInitiative.SelectedValue + " item";
```

Comment: It is getting a value for e.Text but is returning blank value for e.Value

Comment: And if you try this:
Label1.Text = "You selected " + SelectInitiative.SelectedValue + " item";
Instead of using e.Value and see if that works     I have changed already my answer

Comment: I already had the same problem as you on my application. See here :http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/combobox/retrieving-the-value-on-selectedindexchange.aspx

Comment: Now,Its a cry for help plzzzz

Comment: wow this is really strange .. There may be another problem in your code in your page.

Comment: I think the "DataSource" can not bound "ID" as the value for I do not know why. Have you tried to fill the "RadCombobox" manually to see if the problem just the "DataSource"?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and for me the source was that I was setting the datasource on every AutoPostBack. Make sure that you're not reinitializing the items in the combo box before the event triggers.